# how to access shared_preferences stored in flutter inside swiftui widget

Tags: swift, flutter, userdefaults, widgetkit

I have a flutter app in which I have set shared_preferences, now I am creating a widget which is then done in native using swiftUI and WidgetKit. however now I am stuck at how to get the value of preferences which I stored in flutter as I have searched that flutter shared_preferences stores it in swiftUI UserDefaults. I have tried different solutions but still no luck, follows what I have tried:

1- I have set app group in both app and widget then I have used it like this, note I am calling this inside widget TimelineProvider getTimeline() function.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "app.group.id")
    let value = defaults?.object(forKey: "flutter.KEY")
    print("-- Here \(value ?? "empty")")
```

2- I have done same approach with using standard instead of group id.

also some other minor tweaks which I think will work but no progress. I am new to swift as this is my first project on it so I am making some mistake but don't know what kindly any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes you need use UserDefaults with group identifier. Make sure that you have configured all properly. You will need to create group identifier in apple portal, then add it in entitlements.

Comment: I have done this but no luck. any other tip

Comment: Same code, make sure you have the entitlements setup for app group. Also, something to think about Widgets are like a GIF, and each entry is an image that all adds up to the GIF. Widgets don't listen they have to be told when to "Reload" or when to recreate the GIF. Don't assume that because UserDefaults has a new value that widget will automatically load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying almost everything, I have found a reason why my userdefaults is not giving me data stored in flutter shared_preferences. It is because flutter shared_preferences uses userdefault.standard when storing/setting data hence in my widget it is not available even though I have given both target (App and widget) same group Id is because of this as my flutter Shared_pref package is setting it on standard. To fix this I have applied different approach I have used this [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preference_app_group/versions/1.0.0+1) it allows me to set appGroup inside flutter when then I can use to get value in my swiftUi widget. In background this package uses methodChannels which are used to call a method from flutter to directly set appGroup and values in swiftUi userdefaults. this is my approach and I dont know if it is correct or not as I am new to swift but it works for now.